# Swapping series and linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis

If $T$ is a continuous linear transformation between normed spaces. Under what conditions of $T$ and $(a_n)_n$ we have $T(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(a_n)$?

Comment: Use the definition of "continuous".  And the defintion of "convergence" for the series.  (You also need the definition of "linear").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T\left(\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n\right) = T\left(\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^{N}a_n\right) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}T\left(\sum_{n = 0}^{N}a_n\right) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^{N}T(a_n) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}T(a_n)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume $T:V\rightarrow W$ where $V, W$ are Banach spaces. Then by definition we have 
$$
|Tv|\le |T||v|,\forall v\in V
$$
Therefore trivially you have 
$$
|T(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n})|\le |T||\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_{n}|<\infty
$$
Therefore the map is well defined. The linearity then easily follows from definition.